# Why can't you select "Autosave to cloud" for ironman games created locally?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

A few months ago you didn't have the option to save locally. Now you do, but if you want to save it to the cloud so you can play it elsewhere you can't; the option is greyed out in the game options once you load the game.

Does anyone know why? I see no reason why you shouldn't be able to turn that option on and off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official response from Paradox was, summarized:

We haven't implemented that; it's not on our to-do list for the near future; it probably shouldn't be there; we have no solution for transferring local games to the cloud right now.